# Python xpath parsing

Tags: python, lxml

```
<span class="ct">09月20日 22:40&nbsp;from iphone7</span>
```

I use LXML parsing, how can I use xpath to get '09月20日 22:40 ' and 'from iphone7'?

Comment: You have *just* that text? I don't know if lxml can parse that by itself...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
from lxml import etree

root = etree.fromstring('<span class="ct">09月20日 22:40&nbsp;from iphone7</span>', etree.HTMLParser())
for t in root.xpath('//span[@class="ct"]/text()'):
    month_day, time, device = t.split(maxsplit=2)
    print('month day: {}, time: {}, device: {}'.format(month_day, time, device))
    # output => month day: 09月20日, time: 22:40, device: from iphone7
```

`//span` to get span tag located at any depth
`[@class="ct"]` to get those with class `ct`
`/text()` to get the inner text

See the documentation [here](http://lxml.de/tutorial.html)

Comment: Thank you very much